# What are the differences in the qualifiers used for declaring FatFractal event handlers in FFDL?

Tags: custom-backend

I've noticed a few variations in how event handlers can be defined in FFDL involving the use of certain qualifiers or keywords. For example, I've seen the use of both `POST` and `ASYNC` keywords:

```
CREATE HANDLER SupportRequestCreate ASYNC ON /SupportRequest CREATE AS javascript:require ('scripts/SupportEventHandlers').handleSupportRequestCreate();

CREATE HANDLER UserCreate POST ON /FFUser CREATE AS javascript:require ('scripts/UserEventHandlers').handleUserCreate();
```

Just wondering what are the differences between these keywords (or any other keywords) as it pertains to the behavior of the event handlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keywords you mention specify the timing of event handler execution relative to the triggering event itself. There are three choices:

- `PRE` -- event handler is triggered **synchronously** with the event, and execute **before** the event itself. This is useful for tasks such as validation.
- `POST` -- event handler is triggered **synchronously** with the event, and executes **after** the event itself.
- `ASYNC` -- event handler is triggered **asynchronously** with the event.

Hope this helps!